# Windows Forms MessageBox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, messagebox

I'm using a Message Box in a small tool I'm coding in Visual Studio, which runs daily and outputs information to a pop up window on my desktop. However if I have another window open, the message box gets lost behind it and can go unnoticed. I was wondering if there is any way to ensure that the message box is always shown on top of all other open desktop applications. Also, is there a way to create a message box that won't allow me to do anything else on the desktop without first exiting the message box? For example, I can't open another application on top of the message box until the message box is gone.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or alternatives you have! This is my first time using the MessageBox object so I have very limited understanding of its capabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to keep your form top most from other forms in your own application you could use

```
MyForm.TopMost = true;
```

Otherwise if you wish to keep your application on top of other windows in Windows operating system you have to call a Win32 function. Here's an example

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOPMOST = new IntPtr(-1);
        static readonly IntPtr HWND_NOTOPMOST = new IntPtr(-2);
        static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOP = new IntPtr(0);
        static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1);
        const UInt32 SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001;
        const UInt32 SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002;
        const UInt32 TOPMOST_FLAGS = SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE;

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetWindowPos(this.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, TOPMOST_FLAGS);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Vote and Accept the answer if that answered your question

Answer (score 1):

The `MessageBox` doesn't have a way to set it as `TopMost`. It'll appear on top of other forms in your own program, but not necessarily on top of other programs.

You could create your own `Form` and design it to *look* like a `MessageBox`, then set the `TopMost` property to `True`. That will display it on top of most windows.

But it's still no guarantee. If you're running another application that *also* has stuff set to `TopMost`, then it won't appear on top of those. Even if there were `TopMoster` and `TopMostestest` properties... well... multiple programs could use those too.

In the end, there's really no guarantee of making sure your window appears above everything else the user is doing.

As an alternative, maybe you could do some research on the [NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon(v=vs.110).aspx) class, and display the message in a popup balloon in the taskbar? That would grab attention too, without interrupting whatever you're in the middle of.